# Getting the same value for R, G and B

Tags: java, image, colors

I am messing with `java.awt.color` and `java.awt.image` to get to know what I can do with these packages.

I created a class that generates an image with random colors for each pixel and then another class that is supposed to apply some "effects" of this image and save a new one.

Here's how I declare the image in the first class:

`private BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);`

and save it in a PNG file. Then with the other class I read it

`BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("img.png"));`

and I try to split the R, G and B colors in three different bidimensional arrays:

```
for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
        Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(i, j));
        R[i][j] = c.getRed();
        G[i][j] = c.getGreen();
        B[i][j] = c.getBlue();
    }
```

Buuut, when I print R, G and B they all three have the same exact values... What's happening?

Comment: Can we see the code where you assign the random colors to the image pixels?

Comment: What "exact same value" do you get? Is it the same for every pixel? What does the input image look like (have you displayed it)? How did you originally set the random pixel values?  What have you done to debug this?

Comment: If `R={1,2,3}` then `G={1,2,3}` and `B={1,2,3}` That's what I mean when I say they all have the same value... How do I set random values? Plain simple: `imagen.setRGB(i, j, new Color(rnd.nextInt(255), rnd.nextInt(255), rnd.nextInt(255)).getRGB());` Also, how do people down vote so easily? Gosh.

Comment: If you print out the numbers individually at each step, by using `c.getRed()` like `System.out.println("Red:"+c.getRed());`, does each step have the same colors as well?  I would venture a guess it's a problem with your arrays, in that I venture they are referencing the same array, so changing one changes the value in all 3.

Comment: @CodeChimp you're absolutely right. Thanks.

Comment: A broken clock is write twice a day.